# How increase in specifity of a selector affects jQuery performance?

Tags: jquery

In other words, which line is easier for jQuery to perform: `$("#id3")` or `$("#id1 #id2 #id3")`, where `id1`,`id2` and `id3` are nested divs' ids. Are there any rules for writing fast jQuery selectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#id3')` is quicker for jQuery to do, as it detects the special case of a single `#` selector and redirects to `document.getElementById()`. It's also clearly simpler; you should use a single ID selector unless you really do need to check that the element with `id="id3"` is inside the element with `id="id2"`.

Note that for most other standard CSS selectors like this (ie not the questionable Sizzle-specific selectors like `:first`), jQuery will try to use the `querySelectorAll()` method of modern browsers, so the speed of Sizzle matters less than the browser's own performance, making it a different question.